# Label every nth element by group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My data consists of a set of observations made on different groups. There is a different number of observations for each group. I would like to create a variable that flags an observation with a "1" for further manual QA/QC. The flags should be regularly spaced within a group, but that spacing may be different between two groups. The spacing is derived by dividing the length of each group by a constant (5 for this example).

The data would look something like this:

```
dt<-data.table(places=c(rep("A",10), rep("B",20))) #the data
dt2<-data.table(places=c("A","B"), spacing=c(2,4)) #the spacings by group to apply to the data
```

Some code is then applied to generate a flagging (or sequence)

```
dt$sequence<- ????
```

Which looks like:

```
places  sequence
A       1
A   
A       1
A   
...
B       1
B   
B   
B
```

Essentially I want to have each group "count off" based on an ideal spacing that has been determined for that group and only retain the "1" each time the count recycles.  I am just not sure how to feed data.table that spacing and group combination.

Comment: This is straightforward with `dplyr`, but I'm curious as to the precise rules you use for determining the spacing.  If the column length is not divisible by the corresponding `spacing`, do you want to round down to the nearest integer, or round up to the nearest integer...or something else altogether? Could you perhaps provide a function `f <- function(col_length, spacing_divisor){...}` to precisely define your intent?

Comment: Sure, `f<-function(col_length){floor(col_length/5}`  The dplyr solution will be interesting to see, but I am really interested in the data.table solution.

Comment: Thanks!  Answer coming right up!

Comment: I should point out that your example output shows `1` occurring every 2 rows for `"A"`, rather than once at the beginning and once at the halfway point...which is what `f` would provide when supplied with `2` and asked to divide the group into 2 equal parts.

Comment: hmmm I don't see the issue. I was imagining my function being applied by group. I realized my solution is easier than I was making it. See below.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option:

```
dt[, sq := dt2[.SD, on=.(places), +((rowid(i.places)-1) %% spacing == 0L)]]
```

output:

```
    places sq
 1:      A  1
 2:      A  0
 3:      A  1
 4:      A  0
 5:      A  1
 6:      A  0
 7:      A  1
 8:      A  0
 9:      A  1
10:      A  0
11:      B  1
12:      B  0
13:      B  0
14:      B  0
15:      B  1
16:      B  0
17:      B  0
18:      B  0
19:      B  1
20:      B  0
21:      B  0
22:      B  0
23:      B  1
24:      B  0
25:      B  0
26:      B  0
27:      B  1
28:      B  0
29:      B  0
30:      B  0
```

You can *feed data.table that spacing and group combination* using a join `dt2[.SD, on=.(places)` then generate a sequence using `rowid` and then modulo to find those rows that the seq integer is divisible by the the spacing.

Comment: Thanks for translating my approach to `data.table`!  I was wondering what that would look like.  I'm pretty well invested in `dplyr` for now, but sooner or later one must surrender to the raw power of `data.table`.  :D

Answer (score 1):

I arrived at the data.table solution :

```
dtest[, sequence := rep(seq_len(floor(.N/5)),length.out=.N), by = places]
dtest[sequence!=1,sequence:=NA]
```

... never used length.out before....

Comment: Nice!  But doesn't this just use the same `spacing` (here `5`) for every group?  What about the individual spacings by group given by `spacing = c(2, 4)` in `dt2`?

Comment: I am ignoring dt2 now because I realized it was unnecessary. It would be easier to wrap into the definition of `sequence`. It is using the same number of 1s (5) for each group, but with different spacing. `.N` is DT shorthand for the length of the group. A is length 10 and B is length 20 so the calculated spacing becomes 2 and 4.

Comment: So just to be clear, you have no use for "custom" spacing for each group, as provided in a separate `dt2`?  For example, you couldn't calculate the spacing as 2 and 13 using the same divisor.

Comment: I see what you are saying. If I don't like the calculated spacing I could supply a custom spacing by dt2. That could be helpful.  I don't need it for this version, but when protocol deviations occur (and they do occur) it could be helpful.

Comment: OK, well I have both versions queued up with `dplyr` if you're interested.

Comment: post them, curious to see those solutions. Thanks @Greg

Comment: Just posted them.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Per our [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215591/label-every-nth-element-by-group-in-data-table/68215935#comment120563399_68215935), here are the `dplyr` solutions, which each start with

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)


dt <- data.table(places=c(rep("A",10), rep("B",20))) #the data
```

for both approaches discussed:

1. The universal divisor (here `5`):

```
    # The divisor to be applied universally across all groups.
    universal_divisor <- 5
    
    # The vectorized function you specified.
    f <- function(group_length, divisor){
      return(floor(group_length / divisor))
    }
    
    dt_universal <- dt %>%
      # Group in order to index each row WITHIN its group.
      group_by(places) %>%
      # Mark a 1 at each point calculated by the given function 'f' from the group
      # group size, against the universal divisor; otherwise make blank (NA).
      mutate(sequence = if_else(row_number() %% f(n(), universal_divisor) == 0,
                                   1, as.numeric(NA))) %>%
      ungroup() %>% as.data.table()
```

2. The custom spacings:

```
    # Your spacings by group to apply to the data.
    dt2 <- data.table(places=c("A","B"), spacing=c(2,4))
    
    dt_custom <- dt %>%
      # Match each row to the custom spacing value for its 'place'.
      left_join(dt2, by = "places") %>%
      # Group in order to index each row WITHIN its group.
      group_by(places) %>%
      # Mark with a 1 at the desired spacing; otherwise make blank (NA).
      transmute(places,
                sequence = if_else(row_number() %% spacing == 0,
                                   1, as.numeric(NA))) %>%
      ungroup() %>% as.data.table()
```

Each of approaches will output the `data.table` below. While some of these operations can be done more efficiently with `data.table`, I personally find the `dplyr` workflow very transparent and flexible.

```
    places sequence
 1:      A       NA
 2:      A        1
 3:      A       NA
 4:      A        1
 5:      A       NA
 6:      A        1
 7:      A       NA
 8:      A        1
 9:      A       NA
10:      A        1
11:      B       NA
12:      B       NA
13:      B       NA
14:      B        1
15:      B       NA
16:      B       NA
17:      B       NA
18:      B        1
19:      B       NA
20:      B       NA
21:      B       NA
22:      B        1
23:      B       NA
24:      B       NA
25:      B       NA
26:      B        1
27:      B       NA
28:      B       NA
29:      B       NA
30:      B        1
    places sequence
```